# Double click как доработать код для нескольких кнопок

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем добра! Снова нужна помощь. Пишу небольшое приложение, имеется несколько кнопок выполняющих разные задачи при одном нажатии (SingleClick) и двух (DoubleClick). Для этого нашел скрипт на форуме. Все работает идеально с одной кнопкой, добавил еще 2 кнопки и заметил, что при быстром нажатии к примеру btn1 и btn2 срабатывает doubleClick для btn2, То есть необходимо чтобы, DoubleClick срабатывал при двойном нажатии одной и той же кнопки, подскажите как подправить скрипт под несколько кнопок. Заранее извиняюсь если объясняю сумбурно, я новичок и немного плаваю в терминологии.
Скопированный скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class DoubleClickTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float doubleClickTimeLimit = 0.35f;
    bool clickedOnce = false;
    public Button = btn1, btn2, btn3;
    float count = 0f;


    void Start(){
        btn1.onClick.AddListener(Task1);
        btn2.onClick.AddListener(Task2);
        btn3.onClick.AddListener(Task3);
    }
    public void startClick(){
        StartCoroutine (ClickEvent ());
    }
    public IEnumerator ClickEvent()
    {
        if (!clickedOnce && count < doubleClickTimeLimit) {
            clickedOnce = true;
        } else {
            clickedOnce = false;
            yield break;  //If the button is pressed twice, don't allow the second function call to fully execute.
        }
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        while(count < doubleClickTimeLimit)
        {
            if(!clickedOnce)
            {
                DoubleClick();
                count = 0f;
                clickedOnce = false;
                yield break;
            }
            count += Time.deltaTime;// increment counter by change in time between frames
            yield return null; // wait for the next frame
        }
        SingleClick();
        count = 0f;
        clickedOnce = false;
    }
    private void SingleClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("Single Click");
    }

    private void DoubleClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("Double Click");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У тебя отсчёт времени до 2-го нажатия единый для всех кнопок.

Вариант 1. Раздели скрипты на:

```
DoubleClickTest1 
DoubleClickTest2
```

Вариант 2. Определяй какая нажата кнопка (например по тегу или имени) и считай отдельно

```
clickedOnce1
clickedOnce2
```

Вариант 3. Определяй какая нажата кнопка и храни `clickedOnce` внутри кнопки/объекта

Comment: 1 вариант думал, Но у меня больше 10 кнопок поэтому не хотелось бы. 2 вариант думаю подойдет спасибо!